# OpenCart 2.0 Y.CMS настройка Яндекс.Метрика

Tags: opencart

Проблема такая, не могу получить токен OAuth в Y.CMS от Яндекс.Кассы. Получаю код подтверждения, но не пойму как обменять код подтверждения на токен!!!

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score -1):

[ссылка](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjG5eHG757QAhUHliwKHXf9AL4QFggqMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkassa.yandex.ru%2Ffiles%2Fmanual_y.cms_opencart2.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHIOgMPqDa8dOVz2U9J2eK_mabAkQ) Здесь мануал. Прочтите и сделайте все как там. У меня такая же проблема была - помогло.

Comment: Пожалуйста опишите, чем вам помог мануал. Или вкратце опишите изменение, которое устранило ошибку.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.